# fprintf starts printing with strange characters then proceeds to print normally

Tags: c, file, printf

I have run into a problem when trying to write to file using fprintf(). When I start writing into file the first few lines are composed of semi-random invalid characters and after that the rest is printed normally. I have no idea what can cause the problem. Below is the code that produces the problem.

functions called:

```
double calc_time(clock_t s, clock_t e){
    return ((double)(e-s) / (sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)));
}

void print_times(FILE *f, char *operation, clock_t s, clock_t e, struct tms *st, struct tms *et){
    printf("%s", operation);
    printf("\nREAL TIME: %f\n", calc_time(s,e));
    printf("USER TIME: %f\n", calc_time(st->tms_utime,et->tms_utime));
    printf("SYS TIME: %f\n", calc_time(st->tms_stime,et->tms_stime));
    printf("HERE");
    fprintf(f,"%s", operation);
    fprintf(f,"\nREAL TIME: %fl", calc_time(s,e));
    fprintf(f,"\nUSER TIME: %fl", calc_time(st->tms_utime,et->tms_utime));
    fprintf(f,"\nSYS TIME: %fl", calc_time(st->tms_stime,et->tms_stime));
}
```

and the printing takes place here:

```
    f = fopen("raport2.txt","a");

    clock_t r_times[2];
    struct tms* t_times[2];
    t_times[0] = calloc(1,sizeof(struct tms));
    t_times[1] = calloc(1,sizeof(struct tms));

    r_times[0] = times(t_times[0]);

    struct block_array* array = create(4);
    r_times[1] = times(t_times[1]);

    print_times(f, "\nCreating array", r_times[0], r_times[1], t_times[0], t_times[1]);

    r_times[0] = times(t_times[0]);

    struct file_sequence seq = seq_def("t1.txt t2.txt b1.txt b2.txt");
    char *tmp = compare(seq);
    create_blocks(array,tmp,4);
    r_times[1] = times(t_times[1]);

    print_times(f,"\nCreating blocks",r_times[0],r_times[1],t_times[0],t_times[1]);

    r_times[0] = times(t_times[0]);

    delete_block(array,1);
    delete_block(array,2);
    delete_block(array,3);
    delete_block(array,4);
    r_times[1] = times(t_times[1]);

    print_times(f, "\nDeleting blocks", r_times[0], r_times[1], t_times[0], t_times[1]);
```

Comment: `t_times[0] = calloc(1,sizeof(struct tms)); ...  r_times[0] = times(t_times[0]);` is strange.  What is the point of sending to `times()` a `struct tms` filled with zeros?  Did you mean `times(&t_times[0]);`  If so, enable all warnings and save time.

Comment: Note you're appending to the file.  You're sure you're getting the garbage characters each time, and not just looking at what was left over from a previous run of the program?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: To be more specific, it,s always the first call to print_times tahat prints invalid characters, and even when I start with a new empty file the problem occurs. Also I tried the change to  `times(&t_times[0])` and this has produced warnings about incompatible pointer type.

Comment: Here is the code that reproduces the problem for me:
https://github.com/KonradPR/fprintf_problem

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by a different part of code than provided in the snippets (although the github source will still reproduce it). It turns out that in a different part of program I was writing to a file without erasing it's previous contents (I thought that `touch` does that), then data retrieved from the file was causing memory leaks and all kinds allocation problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%lf` to print doubles, rather than the typo `%fl` you're using.

Comment: The typo simply means that the values will be printed with an `l` (lower-case ell) after them.  Both `%f` and `%lf` are correct formats for printing `double` — and there is no way to print a `float` since those are always converted to `double` by the rules for calling a variadic function like `fprintf()`.